# Python std.stdout.write loop problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure of what's going on here, but I have some python code:

```
import sys

max_cols = 350
max_rows = 1
r1 = range(max_rows)
r2 = range(max_cols)

for y in r1:
    for x in r2:
        sys.stdout.write('something')
        if x is not max_cols-1:
            sys.stdout.write(',')
```

Now, this works fine for values of max_cols <= 257.
However, if you use >= 258, you end up with an extra ',' at the end.
(The idea here is obviously to generate a CSV file.)

Now, 256 is a CS number, so there's clearly something going on here that I'm unaware of, since everything works perfectly up until that point.  This also happens when I try to write to a file using the same pattern.

Why does this happen?

Using Python 3.2.

Comment: I really wouldn't use `sys.stdout.write()` for this.

Comment: Anything wrong with the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html)?

Comment: And what's wrong with `print()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` is **not** for checking equality but for checking identity. `x is y` is only true if both variables refer to the same object. As it happens, CPython resuses objects for small integers - but in general, the concept of identity is very different from the concept of equality. Use the correct operators, `==` and `!=` for equality and inequality respectively, and it works.

Also note that the code can be made much simpler and robust by just using the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Using != worked, thanks!  I was also unaware of the csv module.

Answer (score 2):

The CPython implementation caches small numbers, so all instances of the number `12` are the same object. The `is` operator compares the *identities* of objects, not their values. What you wanted to do was use the `!=` operator to compare the values.

It's likely that your instance of the CPython implementation caches numbers up to 256.

Incidentally, whenever you bump into a pattern like this, where you have to drop the last separator from a list of delimited things, [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) is probably what you wanted.

Comment: `.join` is a method of `str`.